# Debugging Java project in VSCODE

Tags: java, visual-studio-code

I am a relative newbie to VSCODE.  It worked for me very well whilst debugging in GO.

The project shows no problems.

But in Java I clicked `Start Debugging` and get this in the Terminal window:-

> PS C:\Users\steve\Documents\JavaWorkSpace>  & 'c:\Users\steve.vscode\extensions\vscjava.vscode-java-debug-0.26.0\scripts\launcher.bat' 'C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_251\bin\java.exe' '-agentlib:jdwp=transport=dt_socket,server=n,suspend=y,address=localhost:54104' '-Dfile.encoding=UTF-8' '-cp' 'C:\Users\steve\AppData\Roaming\Code\User\workspaceStorage\b9812d9a2523f252a1ef08f094c40f7e\redhat.java\jdt_ws\JavaWorkSpace_9d6a9741\bin' 'artifactID.src.main.java.mrs.src.java.App'
> PS C:\Users\steve\Documents\JavaWorkSpace>

I put a breakpoint on the first executable statement which it didn't hit???

Any ideas would be helpful.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that your java program is not actually running so you're not able to debug it. The way I usually debug my java files is that the fourth option from the top in VS bar. It should have an icon with a bug and run on it. Once you're in that section put your breakpoints and hit 'run and debug'.

If that doesn't help check that you have JAVA selected in your debug configuration.

[VS Code Debug Guide](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/debugging)

Answer (score 0):

The project structure as messed up. So I went back to Eclipse.

Not what I wanted to do but expedient.

Steve